# Elastic search sorting by timestamp without the sort query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

So i have a program that I'm using, which uses Elastic search under the hood, I want to get the documents from an index and sort them by timestamp where timestamp has a mapping of type "integer". I can write a query but the sorting part is fixed to:

```js
{
    //.....
    "sort": [
        {
             "id.keyword": { "order": "asc" }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to make use of the scoring or something to make this work?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to sort the data, by some criteria, you are specifically not providing in the `sort` ?

Comment: @Paulo yes, so i need to sort them by Timestamp, but inside the `sort` the data is sorted by id, and i cant change that, its automatically injected by the app im using

Comment: Well you need to change that.

Comment: @Paulo change what? The `sort` cant be changed its injected by the application and whatever sort i try to use, it gets ignored